# uninstall vmware deleted lib files by mistake?

Tags: uninstall, vmware

I wanted to uninstall the VMware horizon client I couldn't do it so I opened /lib directory from the terminal and deleted 1-2 directories related to VMware this is from where I deleted[/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh2Xe.png) now neither VMware in is installed nor its opening nothing is happening while clicking on it[desktop icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9u6l.jpg) there are some directories in /bin related to VMware[/bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c89Wl.png) idk what they are. I am very much new to Linux pls help me to completely remove or uninstall from the system so that I can install fresh because without uninstalling I can't install fresh.
os is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS desktop 64-bit gnome version 3.36.8

Comment: By not using the official way of removing software (see `man apt dpkg aptitude`), you have broken your system. Reinstall. Boot from an install CD/USB, and be sure to find and uncheck the "`Format`" boxes.

Comment: FYI: Your system keeps a list of what packages are installed; those installed packages means specific files were installed on the system. It won't re-install them by default (*no need as they're present according to the installed packages database*), but that database no longer matches what you have as you didn't remove using package tools.  You can `apt install --reinstall` for each package that will cause the files to be re-populated if you know what exactly you removed; but a restore from backups, or re-install is usually the fallback if you don't know exactly what you removed.

Comment: i removed vmware packages from /lib so how i can use apt install --reinstall according to that?

Comment: also what is meant be reinstall? ive to reinstall format whole system and reinstall ubuntu? or reinstall vmware horizon

Comment: Packages & files are different concepts. A package can contain 1 or more files. Say you removed a single file (`/usr/share/doc/base-files/FAQ`) you can use `dpkg -S` to find out it's provided by [base-files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/base-files) meaning that package would cause it to be restored.  You didn't say what files you erased; thus why restoration of backups OR re-install were suggested first. My suggestion assumes you know what **exactly** was removed (ie. actual file detail).  Inside a directory can many files, meaning many packages will need fixing...

Comment: Another option would be create a like system to look what should be there; and use that as a basis for what will likely need to be reinstalled (*I've done this before; as a learning exercise after I made a mistake... it took way longer than restoring of data or re-install; but doing it is a sure way to consider the consequences to subsequent & careless `rm` commands*...)

Comment: oh okay then acc. to this idk which files i removed there were 2-3 directories related to vmware in /lib i removed them all idk name or anything about them. so what should i do now?

Comment: when i again try to intstall vmware through gui installer it says already installed and terminal shows installation done

Comment: I mentioned that before; the package list says it's installed as you installed it earlier... thus the need to `install --reinstall` I covered earlier.

Comment: i ran this commnad nothing happened 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. this is what came

Comment: Read back... I mentioned for each package that needs to be re-installed.. ie. in my base-files example it was `sudo apt install --reinstall base-files` which would cause the package `base-files` to be re-installed, a process you need to do for each package where you deleted libraries/files in the directory...

Comment: E: Unable to locate package VMware-Horizon
idk the package name :( :(

Comment: You write that you "*can't install fresh*." That's too bad. A fresh install would quickly solve the problems that you created.

Comment: hi all the problem was solved without any boot from CD or anything like that...i simply entered my computer local folder as a super user i accidently files realted to vmware from /lib folder before so one by one i entered each folder like /etc /usr /bin etc. and deleted any files related to vmware with rm-rf command then i tried to reinstall vmware it was succesfully installed and running now.

Answer (score 0):

Most people who addressed this question don't realise that vmware is not installed using apt and is not visible to the package manager. It's a piece of software (.bundle package) that you download from the vmware website. There are instructions for removing it on the vmware website, but they might not work. Basically removing it can be a pain on linux. The poster manually deleted all the files he could find related to vmware. I had to do the same, it's slow, but it works. Maybe not the best way, but you can find and delete the files by opening files with `sudo nautilus`